# Error:null value in entry: aaptFriendlyManifestOutputFile=null

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.3

I keep getting error when building my project in Android Studio

`Error:null value in entry: aaptFriendlyManifestOutputFile=null`

How do I fix this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

delete the folder on this path : ...\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts and build project again, this folder build by gradle again. Now everything works.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to delete whole .gradle folder and in new android studio you might not find the taskArtifacts file so delete taskHistory file only and rebuild the project.

Comment: +1, deleting only that folder solved the problem: very efficient, instead of deleting the whole .gradle folder

Comment: there was taskHistory file inside taskHistory folder. Deleting only taskHistory file did not work. Deleting "taskHistory folder" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the *.gradle* folder in the project root directory solved the problem.
Just rebuild the project afterwards.